# Event handler code snippet absent from PCL project in Xamarin.Forms, VS 2017

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Previously in UWP apps I had used a code snippet that generated an event handler and linked it to a xaml control's event. For instance, a button and I type Click and it prompts me to create a new event handler. 
In Xamarain forms, I get the same thing in UWP version of the app, but not in the MainPage.xaml inside the first project. In other words, if my app is named WorkingDemo, the snippet works in WorkingDemo.UWP project, but not in WorkingDemo. In previous versions this section was called the PCL i believe. 
Also, if I type out:

```
Click=""
```

and put my cursor between the quote and hit ctrl+space nothing happens at all.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you download **Resharper** for Visual Studio, it is very good and helps not only in these situations. You quickly get used to it.
About the license: I use a student license, they activate it very quickly

Almost all .Net programmers use it as their assistant

Comment: That's fine and all, and I'm giving resharper a try, but my question really was about Visual Studio's default capabilties. Already resharper seems laggy, and needlessly distracting with it's annotations.  I can't see paying $300 a year for it.

Answer (score 0):

Resharper really slows down the launch and operation of visual studio. But don't always need to pay :)

As for visual studio, there is a workaround: you can write `Clicked = ""` in Xaml, then go to the code file and somewhere to write for example `button.Clicked + = ...`, then IntelliSense prompts you to generate the handler, you generate it and delete the `button .Clicked + = ...` from the code file.
The last thing you need to do is copy the name of the generated event handler to the xaml markup